# Gluu Oxauth error while creating it in container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, security, identity-management, gluu

I have directly pull the oxauth private image from the docker hub repo (gluu federation)

```
docker pull gluufederation/oxauth:4.5.3-1
```

root@testing-gluu-installation:/home/jackazjimmy# docker run -p 8500:8500 --name oxauth2

```
b9bb2e54e80f WARNING - pygluu.containerlib.wait - 2024-01-11 12:05:58,476 - Config is not ready; reason=HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8500): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/kv/gluu/config/hostname
```